dirent.h library in Visual Studio
How do you upload the "dirent.h" library in Visual Studio?
I tried to put it in the header files and then I did include "dirnet.h" and it didn't work
It tells me “Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E1696 cannot open source file "dirent.h" project     10
"

Show the piece of code that triggers the error.

it was this #include "dirent.h" , but i someone helped me already I just had to put the library in the code folder as well,  thanks tho!
